# Parsing HTML with Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

With this HTML code:

```html
<div class="one">
  .....
</div>
<div class="one">
  .....
</div>
<div class="one">
  .....
</div>
<div class="one">
  .....
</div>
```

How can I select with Nokogiri the second or third div whose class is one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```rb
page.css('div.one')[1] # For the second
page.css('div.one')[2] # For the third
```

Comment: Originally this answer had the CSS `div#one`. That finds a div with an *id* of `one`, but the HTML has *classes* of `one`. That's why I made the CSS `div.one`. `#` selects an ID, `.` selects a class.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Ruby to pare down a large results set to specific items:

```
page.css('div.one')[1,2]  # Two items starting at index 1 (2nd item)
page.css('div.one')[1..2] # Items with indices between 1 and 2, inclusive
```

Because Ruby indexing starts at zero you must take care with which items you want.

Alternatively, you can use CSS selectors to find the [*n*th item](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo):

```
# Second and third items from the set, jQuery-style
page.css('div.one:eq(2),div.one:eq(3)')

# Second and third children, CSS3-style
page.css('div.one:nth-child(2),div.one:nth-child(3)')
```

Or you can use XPath to get back specific matches:

```
# Second and third children
page.xpath("//div[@class='one'][position()=2 or position()=3]")

# Second and third items in the result set
page.xpath("(//div[@class='one'])[position()=2 or position()=3]")
```

With both the CSS and XPath alternatives note that:

1. Numbering starts at 1, not 0
2. You can use `at_css` and `at_xpath` instead to get back the first-such matching element, instead of a NodeSet.

   ```
   # A NodeSet with a single element in it:
   page.css('div.one:eq(2)')

   # The second div element
   page.at_css('div.one:eq(2)')
   ```

Finally, note that if you are selecting a single element by index with XPath, you can use a shorter format:

```
# First div.one seen that is the second child of its parent
page.at_xpath('//div[@class="one"][2]')

# Second div.one in the entire document
page.at_xpath('(//div[@class="one"])[2]')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the plentiful amount of examples. We need more answers like this! +1